# Button cancel JFileChooser still load file when clicked

Tags: java, swing, filechooser

You know, I have button to choose a file using `JFileChooser`. This is my code

```
private void buttonFIleBrowserInPanelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                         
    try {

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
        chooser.setDialogTitle("Please, choose your main file ... ");

        chooser.setFileFilter(new FileFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File f) {
                return f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".java") || f.isDirectory();
            }

            @Override
            public String getDescription() {
                return "Java File (*.java)";
            }
        });
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(true);
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null); 

        File f = chooser.getCurrentDirectory();
        File ff = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        mainFile = ff;
        if (ff != null) { 
            nameFile = ff.toString();

            File namaFilenya = new File(nameFile);
            try {
                FileReader readFile = new FileReader(namaFilenya);
                String readFileToString = readFile.toString();

                try {
                    txtFile.read(readFile, null); // this is the textArea that show the contains of file
                    txtPathMainFile.setText(nameFile); //this is the textarea that show the path of file

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);

            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

When I clicked one of file in chooser and then click OK, it success to load everything that I need. But, in another case when I clicked file but I decided to choose cancel,  the file is still load in my textArea. How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 4):

Check the response of the [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html).

sample code:

```
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " +
        chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
   // rest your code goes here
}
```

You can check for [CANCEL_OPTION](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#CANCEL_OPTION) as well.

For information about using JFileChooser, see [How to Use File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html), a section in The Java Tutorial.

Comment: `chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);`  Nice call on changing that to `parent`..  The rest is good to, but that part really jumped out at me.  :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson It's a sample code, It's good practice to pass the parent of the dialog box.

Comment: *"It's good practice to pass the parent of the dialog box."*  +1 We are in agreement.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the value returned by the `JFileChooser`. See example from my answer

```
int rv = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
if (rv == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
  File file= chooser.getSelectedFile();
```

Comment: It's for something not special here. It should be file, for sure.

Comment: The part with file is not a main part in my answer, and it is an answer without doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether the file is selected or not. i.e you must specify some if/else condition in your code.

```
if(fileSelected){

//load in text Area
}else{
//nothing
}
```

there should be some boolean value returned by the instance of JFileChooser.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the help, this code now work, if I make my code like this

```
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File f = chooser.getCurrentDirectory();
            File ff = chooser.getSelectedFile();//
            mainFile = ff;
            if (ff != null) { t
                nameFile = ff.toString();

                File namaFilenya = new File(nameFile);
                try {
                    FileReader readFile = new FileReader(namaFilenya);
                    try {

                        txtFile.read(readFile, null);
                        txtPathMainFile.setText(nameFile);

                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        System.out.println(ex);
                    }

                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);

                }

            }

        }
```

Thanks..